# Interpolation from data plotted with tuples in lists using Python

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, tuples

I have lists with tuples. Is there any way that I can interpolate the graph so that I can find the x when the y equal to specific number?

For example, this is the list I have: (The form: (x, y))

```
testList = [[(0.0, 0.16321045084221542), (0.5, 0.14992804419926076), (1.0, 0.11065532637895514), (1.5, 0.04708907515862726), (2.0, -0.03802861479205555), (2.5, -0.14102850232363529), (3.0, -0.25746055864004425), (3.5, -0.3822538828249663), (4.0, -0.5098763060056799), (4.5, -0.6344823989838556), (5.0, -0.750042167345144), (5.5, -0.8504464361832059), (6.0, -0.9295881546855232), (6.5, -0.9814212354546451), (7.0, -1.0), (7.5, -0.9795029369940005), (8.0, -0.9142444982515833), (8.5, -0.7986782837636315), (9.0, -0.6273943971548426), (9.5, -0.3951131313722883), (10.0, -0.0966765630073454), (10.5, 0.27296085997528263), (11.0, 0.718742042145311), (11.5, 1.2455168707452469), (12.0, 1.8580515496188488), (12.5, 2.5610375682282385), (13.0, 3.359100318716231)], 

[(0.0, 3.945199007815406), (0.5, 3.9143355111694476), (1.0, 3.8226370706824335), (1.5, 3.672732794584979), (2.0, 3.4688535859541165), (2.5, 3.2166250107987775), (3.0, 2.922811878989832), (3.5, 2.5950409577289504), (4.0, 2.24152674173692), (4.5, 1.8708203973719262), (5.0, 1.4915954141769467), (5.5, 1.1124766759626983), (6.0, 0.7419137749030704), (6.5, 0.38809507884546), (7.0, 0.05889647076017157), (7.5, -0.23814239507555024), (8.0, -0.49582141693684445), (8.5, -0.7072692740017781), (9.0, -0.8659237611855242), (9.5, -0.9655072278443139), (10.0, -1.0), (10.5, -0.9636137216085844), (11.0, -0.8507658078900049), (11.5, -0.6560556545698524), (12.0, -0.37424286410281404), (12.5, -0.00022749998495563695), (13.0, 0.47096776983628086)]]
```

After plotting, it results in: 
[image]

I am trying to get the x indexs when y indexs are equal to -1, and 0.

Like this: `result = [[(7.0, -1.0), (x1, 0.0), (x2, 0.0)], [(10, -1.0), (x3, 0.0), (x4, 0.0)]]`

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking about cases where the (x, -1) coordinate may not be in your initial list of points so you would need to interpolate the function? Since in this case the (7, -1) and (10, -1) are in your initial list

Comment: Also are you willing to use a library for this purpose?

Comment: @awarrier99 Yes!!! Could you give me any hint to solve this?

Comment: Yup, I just posted an answer using the `scipy` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions were monotone I would agree with the other solution, but since you are looking at more than one location, I think fitting a spline and using the `.roots()` method is more reliable:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

def find_x_at_y_target(x, y, y_target):
    """Find the corresponding x value at which a smooth-ish function sampled 
       at x, y becomes equal to y_target via spline interpolation."""
    spline = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y - y_target)
    return spline.roots()

def merge(roots, tol=1e-5):
    """Remove duplicate roots which are closer to each other than tol"""
    result = []
    for root in roots:
        if not result or np.abs(result[-1] - root) > tol:
            result.append(root)

    return result

result = []

for test in testList:
    testresult = []
    result.append(testresult)

    x, y = np.array(test).T
    for y_target in [0.0, -1.0]:
        found_xs = find_x_at_y_target(x, y, y_target)
        for found_x in merge(found_xs):
            testresult.append((found_x, y_target))
```

For your test data this results in

```
[[(1.7907321051459066, 0.0),
  (10.1408055626703, 0.0),
  (6.999999134927593, -1.0)],
 [(7.094611008491239, 0.0),
  (12.500269673618083, 0.0),
  (9.999999999995387, -1.0)]]
```

Notice that in this case the spline method returns two roots near -1, which requires some additional processing.

Comment: Nice this is a much better solution, I was also thinking there had to be a better way to find multiple values but couldn't find the function for it

Answer (score 2):

Using [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) you can create the inverse function of x = f(y) and use this interpolation function (which by default uses linear interpolation, but has other modes) in order to find the x-coordinate corresponding to y = -1

```
from scipy import interpolate

testList = [[(0.0, 0.16321045084221542), (0.5, 0.14992804419926076), (1.0, 0.11065532637895514), (1.5, 0.04708907515862726), (2.0, -0.03802861479205555), (2.5, -0.14102850232363529), (3.0, -0.25746055864004425), (3.5, -0.3822538828249663), (4.0, -0.5098763060056799), (4.5, -0.6344823989838556), (5.0, -0.750042167345144), (5.5, -0.8504464361832059), (6.0, -0.9295881546855232), (6.5, -0.9814212354546451), (7.0, -1.0), (7.5, -0.9795029369940005), (8.0, -0.9142444982515833), (8.5, -0.7986782837636315), (9.0, -0.6273943971548426), (9.5, -0.3951131313722883), (10.0, -0.0966765630073454), (10.5, 0.27296085997528263), (11.0, 0.718742042145311), (11.5, 1.2455168707452469), (12.0, 1.8580515496188488), (12.5, 2.5610375682282385), (13.0, 3.359100318716231)], 
[(0.0, 3.945199007815406), (0.5, 3.9143355111694476), (1.0, 3.8226370706824335), (1.5, 3.672732794584979), (2.0, 3.4688535859541165), (2.5, 3.2166250107987775), (3.0, 2.922811878989832), (3.5, 2.5950409577289504), (4.0, 2.24152674173692), (4.5, 1.8708203973719262), (5.0, 1.4915954141769467), (5.5, 1.1124766759626983), (6.0, 0.7419137749030704), (6.5, 0.38809507884546), (7.0, 0.05889647076017157), (7.5, -0.23814239507555024), (8.0, -0.49582141693684445), (8.5, -0.7072692740017781), (9.0, -0.8659237611855242), (9.5, -0.9655072278443139), (10.0, -1.0), (10.5, -0.9636137216085844), (11.0, -0.8507658078900049), (11.5, -0.6560556545698524), (12.0, -0.37424286410281404), (12.5, -0.00022749998495563695), (13.0, 0.47096776983628086)]]

x1 = [c[0] for c in testList[0]]
y1 = [c[1] for c in testList[0]]
x2 = [c[0] for c in testList[1]]
y2 = [c[1] for c in testList[1]]

f1 = interpolate.interp1d(y1, x1)
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(y2, x2)
print(f1(-1), f2(-1))
```

Comment: @ awarrier99 According to the figure above, when x = 0, there are 2 coordinate y. But when I print( f1(0) ), I only got one value (= 1.77661157). How can I get the other one?

Comment: @Joanne unfortunately I don't think that's possible since a function by definition cannot have a value which maps to two separate values (referring to the inverse function which has multiple values for the input 0). You'd have to recognize the two sets of points converging on your y-value and split them and create separate functions to interpolate